# Magento 2 - Issue with inserting rows automatically

Tags: javascript, arrays, zapier

I have an array pulled by Zapier from Magento system, the only issue we're facing is how can we auto insert these data into a row.

Here's a screenshot of the data: http://prntscr.com/hmbocu

I believe somehow, I need to use JS to control the array using foreach, and hopefully, this is possible using Zapier. Looking forward a hint in this regard.

The code below is the item's row that must be controlled.

```
<tbody>
<tr>
<td class="item-info has-extra" style="font-family: &quot;Poppins&quot;, sans-serif, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; vertical-align: top; padding: 10px; border-top: 1px solid #eaeaea;">
        <p class="product-name" style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 5px; font-weight: 700;">{{27698666__items[]name}}</p>
        <p class="sku" style="margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 10px;">{{27698666__items[]parent_item__sku}}</p>
</td>
    <td class="item-qty" style="font-family: &quot;Poppins&quot;, sans-serif, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; vertical-align: top; padding: 10px; border-top: 1px solid #eaeaea; text-align: center;">{{qty}}</td>
    <td class="item-price" style="font-family: &quot;Poppins&quot;, sans-serif, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; vertical-align: top; padding: 10px; border-top: 1px solid #eaeaea; text-align: right;">
        <span class="price">{{27698666__items[]parent_item__price_incl_tax}}</span>
    </td>
</tr>
</tbody>
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I have found the solution, first you need must state the variables that you want to insert per row, i.e (name, price, qty, SKU), then from there, you should be able to douse the following script by defining the variables, and splitting the array into singular.

Hopefully, this helps someone else in this regard.

```
var qty = inputData.qty.split(",");
var name = inputData.name.split('"');
var sku = inputData.sku.split(",");
var price = inputData.price.split(",");
for (var i=0;i<qty.length;i++) {
  if (i==0) var data = "<tr><td class=\"item-info has-extra\" style=\"font-family: &quot;Poppins&quot;, sans-serif, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; vertical-align: top; padding: 10px; border-top: 1px solid #eaeaea;\"><p class=\"product-name\" style=\"margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 5px; font-weight: 700;\">" + name[i] + "</p><p class=\"sku\" style=\"margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 10px;\">" + sku[i] + "</p></td><td class=\"item-qty\" style=\"font-family: &quot;Poppins&quot;, sans-serif, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; vertical-align: top; padding: 10px; border-top: 1px solid #eaeaea; text-align: center;\">" + qty[i] + "</td><td class=\"item-price\" style=\"font-family: &quot;Poppins&quot;, sans-serif, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; vertical-align: top; padding: 10px; border-top: 1px solid #eaeaea; text-align: right;\"><span class=\"price\">" + price[i] + "</span></td></tr>";
  else data = data + "<tr><td class=\"item-info has-extra\" style=\"font-family: &quot;Poppins&quot;, sans-serif, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; vertical-align: top; padding: 10px; border-top: 1px solid #eaeaea;\"><p class=\"product-name\" style=\"margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 5px; font-weight: 700;\">" + name[i] + "</p><p class=\"sku\" style=\"margin-top: 0; margin-bottom: 10px;\">" + sku[0] + "</p></td><td class=\"item-qty\" style=\"font-family: &quot;Poppins&quot;, sans-serif, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; vertical-align: top; padding: 10px; border-top: 1px solid #eaeaea; text-align: center;\">" + qty[i] + "</td><td class=\"item-price\" style=\"font-family: &quot;Poppins&quot;, sans-serif, 'Helvetica Neue', Helvetica, Arial, sans-serif; vertical-align: top; padding: 10px; border-top: 1px solid #eaeaea; text-align: right;\"><span class=\"price\">" + price[0] + "</span></td></tr>";
}
output = {data}
```